# C# Net use shows 2 different things

Tags: c#, windows, command, prompt

The core issue is that when running a command prompt programmatically to delete a connnection from net use shows different results than in the same context, a user opening the command prompt and running net use.

This is the code to delete the connection:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/K net use delete \\IPAddrofserver";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

So what happens is that the connection is successfully deleted programmatically, but if I open the cmd prompt and run net use, I see the connection I just deleted. This connection remaining open causes errors in my program. Whoami shows that the same user is being utilized. So why is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I think its a different instance when you (user with Active Directory) used the CMD, and your applications instance (svchost? or task scheduler?), unless you specify your own credential (domain, username & password) on your ProcessStartInfo, then I think you can sync well with your CMD instance as the user.

Comment: But if the connection was opened programmatically, and closed programmatically, why would the user have an open connection as well? I think you are right, but I am curious as to the flow of events.

Basically it goes Program Opens Connection->Manipulation->Program Closes Connection. Where does the user enter the picture?

Comment: Haha, I can't accurately support that. I think its also a side effect of too much security / session based network services / etc. that might be causing these cases. Is your user a full administrator? Maybe that's why logically an application can open any path within your workstation, while when deleting, it only affects ITS instance and not yours as an admin.